# Rigidity of lower-dimensional lattices in Euclidean groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

## Informal intro / motivation:

Suppose I have an infinite set of atoms arranged in a 2D periodic crystalline "sheet". By crystalline I simply mean that it is preserved by the action of integer linear combinations of a pair of linearly independent translations (which generate a subgroup $\Gamma\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ of the 3D Euclidean group $E(3)$).

[image: crystalline sheet]

It seems to me that there exist deformations of this flat sheet into a cylindrical structure, where $\Gamma$ itself is deformed so that one of the translations becomes a rotation around an axis or more generally, a screw motion. I would like to know what tools are available to think about this.

[image: cylindrical]

## Attempt at math:

Here's my first attempt at formalizing what I want.

> Let $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}^m$ for some $m$ and let $E(d)$ be the group of isometries for $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.  I would like to understand the space $\mathcal{R}$ of homomorphisms $\rho:\Gamma\rightarrow E(d)$ for, say, $d=3, m=2$, ($m\leq d$ generally is interesting to me).

The only thing I could think to do was to represent elements of $E(d)$ by $(d+1)\times(d+1)$-matrices in the standard way and ask about the space of pairs which commute, i.e. solutions to $ab=ba$.  (Is that the correct subvariety to look at?)  It seemed very messy to work with so I wanted to ask here for better ways to approach this.

> What books / surveys should I look at to get started? I suspect I may have to learn about the general case of "non-cocompact" discrete subgroups of Lie groups (about which I know absolutely nothing).

As an example of things I'd like to understand, what is the dimension of $\mathcal{\tilde{R}}=\mathcal{R}/\text{Aut }E(d)$ (i.e. how rigid is $\mathbb{Z}^m$ inside $E(d)$)? I imagine that's probably pretty complicated due to singularities, so is there a simple way to compute the dimension of the space of deformations infinitesimally around a given homomorphism $\rho$?

The things I could find (e.g. [this survey of Gromov and Pansu](http://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/PDF/1%5B78%5D.pdf)) from googling seem to restrict to the case of finite covolume $\Gamma$.

I do not have a lot of knowledge about these matters, so references at an introductory level (hopefully treating plenty of examples in a hands-on way) would be helpful.

Comment: In your setup is $\rho(\Gamma)$ a discrete subgroup of $E(d)$?

Comment: It's natural to consider the space of homomorphisms as it can be viewed as set of real points of some algebraic variety (of commuting $m$-tuples in $E(d)$); then study its subset (probably open in the real topology) of injective discrete representations.

Comment: Also you probably want $\rho$ to be injective. Assuming this there aren't many choices for discrete injective homomorphisms $\mathbb Z^2\to E(3)$. The group $\rho(\Gamma)$ will have to stabilize a $2$-plane where it acts cocompactly in a familiar way (tiling with parallelograms), and then $\rho(\Gamma)$ also acts isometrically in the normal direction. The normal direction is one dimensional so the action is simply a homomorphism $\mathbb Z^2\to O(1)\cong\mathbb Z_2$. For general $m$, $d$ the picture is similar, except that homomorphisms $\mathbb Z^m\to O(d-m)$ could be more complicated.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Actually, thinking more carefully about the pictures it seems that requiring $\rho(\Gamma)$ to be discrete and $\rho$ to be injective may be too strong (so I've deleted my earlier comment). If we require that then it seems to rule out the deformation to "cylinders" that I want to capture.

Comment: For example, consider an isometric $\mathbb Z$-action on $\mathbb R^3$ by a screw motion and multiply it be the translation $\mathbb Z$-action on $\mathbb R$. The result is a $\mathbb Z^2$-action on $\mathbb R^4$ rotating about the $2$-plane that is the product of an axis of the screw motion and teh $\mathbb R$-factor.

Comment: If $\rho(\Gamma)$ is not discrete, your grid will be messed up. For example, if you consider an isometric $\mathbb Z$-action by a screw motion on $\mathbb R^3$ and try adding another $Z$-action on the same $\mathbb R^3$ to get a $\mathbb Z^2$ action, then commutativity will force the latter $\mathbb Z$ to stabilize the axis of the screw motion. Thus on the axis you actually get a $\mathbb Z^2$-action.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I agree with your latest comment.  That is definitely part of the phenomenon I would like to understand.  I am still trying to understand your comment about $\mathbb{R}^4$.  By "the $\mathbb{R}$-factor" (ignoring the typo) I suppose you mean the "extra" factor that is normal to $\mathbb{R}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am just taking the product of two $\mathbb Z$-actions on $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R$. Identifying $\mathbb R^3$ with $\mathbb C\times\mathbb R$ the formula will be as follows: $(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^2$ acts by sending $(z,t,s)$ to $(e^{in}z, t+n, s+m)$ where $s,t$ are real and $z$ is complex. The $2$-plane corresponding to $z=0$ is stabilized by the action.

Comment: A standard source for this material is Chapter 3 in "Spaces of Constant Curvature" by Joseph A. Wolf.

Comment: Concerning local deformations, an important reference is Weil's 1964 paper (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970495, unfortunately in restricted access).

Comment: @YCor: Weil's paper will give the "formal" dimension of $\tilde{R}$ at the equivalence class $[\rho]$ of $\rho$, namely $2z$, where $z$ is the dimension of the centralizer of $\rho(Z^2)$ in $E(d)$. Unfortunately, this number is just the dimension of the Zariski tangent space of $\tilde{R}$ regarded as a stack (at $[\rho]$). By Goldman-Millson, the analytical germ of $\tilde{R}$ at $[\rho]$ is a quadratic cone, but computing its actual dimension and equations is a bit complicated. However, for standard representations $\rho: Z^2\to E(2)< E(d)$ this might be doable.